# SQL query with Ruby and backslash

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
  db.query("
  UPDATE tm
  SET DESCRIPTION = 'SQL Injection (CALL \'C_DB_FUNCTION\')'
  WHERE DESCRIPTION = 'SQL Injection (CALL \'C DB FUNCTION\')';
  ")
```

This query is working on the DB, but when I tried to run it via ruby with `mysql2` gem, I got the below error,

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'C_DB_FUNCTION')' (Mysql2::Error)
```

I guess its because the `backslash`,

How I can escape it or fix it ?

Thanks!

Comment: add escape slash '\'. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences

Comment: `db.query("
  UPDATE tm
  SET DESCRIPTION = 'SQL Injection (CALL \\'C_DB_FUNCTION\\')'
  WHERE DESCRIPTION = 'SQL Injection (CALL \\'C DB FUNCTION\\')';
  ")`

Comment: @dinesh thanks ! write it as an answer and I will mark it as the correct answer for this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Special Character Escape Sequences please find the http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences

`db.query(" UPDATE tm SET DESCRIPTION = 'SQL Injection (CALL \\'C_DB_FUNCTION\\')' WHERE DESCRIPTION = 'SQL Injection (CALL \\'C DB FUNCTION\\')'; ")`